# How to find Triangular Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I read that Gauss's Eureka Theorem says that any positive integer can be represented by at most 3 triangular numbers.  So say I have some positive integer X, how do I find which 3 triangular numbers added together make that Number X?

edit: if there isn't a way to do this without just guessing and combining all combinations of 3 triangular numbers less than X, then is there a program that can do it for me?

edit 2: It looks like for some integers that there is more than 1 way to describe them using 3 triangular numbers. The way to calculate the possible number of ways is using this formula: [image]

http://www.3quarksdaily.com/3quarksdaily/2015/03/last-month-at-3qd-we-discovered-that-while-it-was-invented-to-solve-problems-in-counting-and-probability-pascals-triangle-c.html

I still don't know if there is a formula to find which triangular numbers though :(

Comment: I don't know. I was just guessing.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) it was Gauss who discovered this and entered it in his diary.  Search the page for 1796

Comment: Thanks Ross Millikan I just edited it :)  I just looked at that wiki page before I posted this question too.

Comment: I haven't found an easy proof of the theorem.  It seems likely a proof would come with an algorithm to find the three, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: I deleted my guess that wasn't write to make room for the possible number of triangular numbers formula and the link where I got it from.

Answer (score 2):

( partial answer/hint) A few things, will help along the way, to make guessing easier:

1. odd+odd=even
2. even+even= even
3. odd+even= odd
4. squares are the sum of two consecutive triangular numbers
5. At most: means it may not always be necessary, for that upper bound to occur in any given example.

If we allow 0 to be counted as a triangular number,we can just add 0 until we hit 3.

1 is odd. From 1,2 and 3 above, we can deduce that, at least an odd number of the triangular numbers in the sum, will be odd (which happens to mean it's of odd index if you count 0 as the 0th triangular number).

2 is even. From 1,2,and 3 above, we can deduce that, There are an even number of odd index triangular numbers, in the sum ( includes the possibility of 0 of them).

we can work out the highest index a triangular number could be using $\lfloor sqrt(2X)\rfloor$. So, in conclusion, you can find which three allow you to solve for X, by using restrictions at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

For all natural numbers $x$, $$\sum_{n=1}^x n$$ only create triangular numbers.
Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, it just tells them a mathematical fact about what triangular numbers are.